# Concerning Luzin-(N)-property

Tags: pr.probability, set-theory, real-analysis, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

> **Definition**: a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ has *Luzin-(N)-Property* if $f$ maps any null set to a null set.

By https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Luzin-N-property, it is known that if $f$ has Luzin-(N)-property and measurable, then for almost every real $x$, $f^{-1}(x)$ is countable. Now I have the following question:

> **Question** Is there a function $f$ having  Luzin-(N)-property and a nonnull set $A$ so that for any $x\in A$, $f^{-1}(x)$ is uncountable?

The question has a positive answer under certain set theoretical assumptions. But I want an answer within $\mathrm{ZFC}$.

Comment: Nice question. Do you know the answer now (since you asked it 4 years ago)?

Comment: No, it is still open.